# JSON passes newline as %5C instead of \n

Tags: javascript, json, firefox, newline, cfml

I have a `cfml` struct, like below:

```
<cfscript>
jsonThing=structnew()
            jsonThing.header = "sometext\nsome more\none more line";            
            jsonThing.phone = "(123) 456-6789";
            jsonThing.city="Nukus";
            jsonThing.state="Coolest one";
            jsonThing.zipcode="74000-6000";         
            jsonThing.descript=#description#; //array;
            jsonThing.descript2=#description2#; //array;
</cfscript>
```

A custom protocol `cstprt` has been created and deployed on the client computers (PC, Windows 10).
JSON is sent to clients:

```
function cstprt() {          
             window.location.href='cstprt:/<cfoutput>#SerializeJSON(jsonThing)#</cfoutput>';}
cstprt();
```

Then a desktop app receives this JSON and prints out it on a receipt printer.
It was working fine until Firefox update v.95 came up. Everything else works still fine, except `\n` now comes as `%5C` on the receiving end.
I am not sure if this because of the Firefox update or some Windows update.
Firefox a must browser for us.
**Question is how to make JSON to pass newline as `\n` again?  Please share your expertise.**
What I have done so far:

- Internet search. Lot of `\n` issues/solutions, but not non of them applicable to my case.
- Confirmed that JSON was passed newline as `\n` before and now it `%5C`.
- Tried making `\\n` as online research suggested.

Thank you for reading. I appreciate your time!

Comment: It's not **JSON** that's doing that. It's whatever is sending the JSON text to you.

Comment: I hear you. But, I was expecting my `CFML` struct is converted to JSON with `SerializeJSON`. I am going to test that idea

Comment: It seems gives `\\n`, not `%5C`:    [link](https://cffiddle.org/app/file?filepath=0fe08f5a-06b0-4306-bd82-2ad4da3bd728/bcbbe8c4-5de8-4698-90a0-b499db7c5f37/7235dc1f-6884-4b2d-8a8f-f0257c20c9a2.cfm)

Comment: Still, question is on the table - where it is getting changed?

Comment: There are several issues in your code: In your cfml code you are creating a cfml structure. That's not a JSON struct. But there are key values containg a \n. Usually new lines are created automaically by the cfml serializeJSON() function. Additionally you are echoing description directly. Why? Also, your protocol in your Javascript is missing a slash. Besides, you are saying it's not working because of new lines being url encoded. Did you take a look into your firefox dev tool for any JavaScript exception to see what is happening in detail? Location is a URL and URLs need to be URL encoded.

Comment: Where exactly is the URL encoding happening? On the client side (in JavaScript) or within `SerializeJSON`?

Comment: @AndreasRu Thank you for your input AndreasRu! I am aware that I am converting `CFML` structure to JSON string by using `SerializeJSON()` [https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-functions/functions-s/serializejson.html](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-functions/functions-s/serializejson.html)   Newlines are created in-between values. I need to have `\n` within the value. Missing slash is intentional and it works for us. Thank you for the debugging tip. I'll try it tomorrow. Appreciate your  time, @AnreasRu!

Comment: @SebastianZartner Thank you your input. I'll get back to you tomorrow, as I don't have access to the code at the time. My problem could be URL decoding actually.

Comment: `My problem could be URL decoding actually` Sounds more like an *encoding* problem (ie. should be encoded, but isn't), as AdnreasRu mentioned. Perhaps Firefox might be automatically encoding something differently than it did before. Might check the release notes to see if anything related to that has changed.  https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/95.0/releasenotes/